Android 14 (API Level 34) Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED in .Net MAUI
anyone  face this issue in .NET MAUI.
“Android 14 (API Level 34) Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED.”
When I target android 14 then got it this exception in .NET MAUI. Even our app not used any broadcast service class.
Any one suggest solution.
“Android 14 (API Level 34) Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED.”

Note that if you're using net8.0, the default Target Android Framework as you set under Application > Android Targets is Android 14.0(API Level 34). So you don't need to set it. This setting is used to set the compiling API for the project.
To fix your issue, you can use the <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="32" android:targetSdkVersion="34" in AndroidManifest.xml to meet the Google Play requirement.

Thank you for sharing, do not forget to accept your own answer. By the way, here is a simple about accepting answers
